# Is it possible to retrieve entered tag values from a signed DocuSign document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST API to created an embedded signing for a predefined document template using the /envelopes/{envelopeID}/views/recipient call.  I know it is possible to pre-populate tag values when creating the envelope, but is it possible to retrieve the value the recipient actually provides in a given tag field for use in the application after signing is complete?  If so, does anyone have an example?

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation for a tool.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the DocuSign API to retrieve information from a signed document.

Comment: Seems like a legit question.. Opp wants to know how to get a specific piece of information via the DocuSign API not use an external tool. I think you just misread it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sounds like you are trying to Get Envelope Recipient Status with the optional query include_tabs**

https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf page 133

**Example Request**

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId
    }/recipients/?include_tabs=true

X-DocuSign-Authentication:
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response**

The response returns the recipient types and current routing order. The recipient types includes the
recipient name, email, ID, recipient type, routing order, authentication status (including the date/time
and result of the authentication) status (including the date/time of the status changes) and, if the
recipient status is declined and a reason is required, a decline reason added by the recipient.If the
optional query include_tabs is set to true, the
tabs associated with the recipient are returned.

The following example shows the response json body

**Example Response**

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "height": 11,
            "name": "Text",
            "value": "this is  a test",
            "width": 66,
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "TAB1",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "ed0e8744-6243-4708-9186-0e3ccf4cb3a4",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "93",
            "yPosition": "142",
            "tabId": "2c7b4d94-d958-44df-b5a7-2b530ce914ed"
          }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I believe the confusion came in with the inconsistency of the name of these fields between the UI and the API.  In the UI they are referred to as "Tags" everywhere, but in the API they appear to be called "Tabs"

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are at least a couple of ways to retrieve tab values from the signed (completed) docs.  I believe Justin's answer is one way.  You can also use the **Get Tab Information for a Recipient** API call, which will return tabs information (values included):

URL:

- /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

Method:

- GET

Example from DocuSign [API Docs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation):

```
    GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

    X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json
```

Sample Response:

```
    {
      "approveTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
      }],
      "textTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
      }],
      "signHereTabs":[{
        ...
     }]
    }
```

Comment: This is a good answer too if you are looking for information from a specific recipient.  In my specific case, though, I'm using the embedded signing where I'm never setting a recipient id.  Good info here for others though.