# Docusign Company Field Not Showing - PHP API

Tags: php, soap, docusignapi

I am trying to implement the CompanyTab on a document in DocuSign but it does not appear. It works when set to TextTab but I am using this elsewhere to display a list of postcodes.

I have tried putting the information into a multidimensional array in an effort to use it with a TextTab but this seems to break the page. I cannot seem to find any guides on this.

Please find a code sample below:

```
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere->setXPosition("100");
$signHere->setYPosition("400");
$signHere->setDocumentId("1");
$signHere->setPageNumber("1");
$signHere->setRecipientId("1");
// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));

// add name tab
$nameTab = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$nameTab->setDocumentId("1");
$nameTab->setRecipientId("1");
$nameTab->setPageNumber("1");
$nameTab->setName("name");
$nameTab->setTabLabel("Name");
$nameTab->setValue($name[0]);
$nameTab->setLocked("true");
$nameTab->setXPosition("100");
$nameTab->setYPosition("150"); 
// add the name tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs->setFirstNameTabs(array($nameTab));

// add email tab
$emailTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$emailTab->setDocumentId("1");
$emailTab->setRecipientId("1");
$emailTab->setPageNumber("1");
$emailTab->setName("email");
$emailTab->setTabLabel("Email");
$emailTab->setValue($_SESSION['email']);
$emailTab->setLocked("true");
$emailTab->setXPosition("100");
$emailTab->setYPosition("200"); 
// add the email tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs->setEmailAddressTabs(array($emailTab));

// add company tab
$firmTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$firmTab->setDocumentId("1");
$firmTab->setRecipientId("1");
$firmTab->setPageNumber("1");
$firmTab->setName("company");
$firmTab->setTabLabel("Company");
$firmTab->setValue($_SESSION['company']);
$firmTab->setLocked("true");
$firmTab->setXPosition("100");
$firmTab->setYPosition("250"); 
// add the company tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs->setCompanyTabs(array($firmTab));

// add phone tab
$phoneTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Number();
$phoneTab->setDocumentId("1");
$phoneTab->setRecipientId("1");
$phoneTab->setPageNumber("1");
$phoneTab->setName("phone");
$phoneTab->setTabLabel("Phone");
$phoneTab->setValue($_SESSION['phone']);
$phoneTab->setLocked("true");
$phoneTab->setXPosition("100");
$phoneTab->setYPosition("300"); 
// add the phone tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs->setNumberTabs(array($phoneTab));

// add postcode tab
$postcodeTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$postcodeTab->setDocumentId("1");
$postcodeTab->setRecipientId("1");
$postcodeTab->setPageNumber("1");
$postcodeTab->setName("postcodes");
$postcodeTab->setTabLabel("Postcodes");
$postcodeTab->setValue($postcodes);
$postcodeTab->setLocked("true");
$postcodeTab->setXPosition("100");
$postcodeTab->setYPosition("350"); 
// add the postcodes tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs->setTextTabs(array($postcodeTab));
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're generating Text objects and injecting them into different tab types. (An EmailAddress tab in DocuSign is automatically filled out to the recipients email address. If you want this to be a fillable field, you'd use a text tab.) Multiple text tabs can be assigned in the setTextTabs array.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Can you provide an example of this with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using multiple text tabs make sure you are only calling the `setTextTabs()` function once.

```
  // add company tab
  $firmTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
  $firmTab->setDocumentId("1");
  $firmTab->setRecipientId("1");
  $firmTab->setPageNumber("1");
  $firmTab->setName("company");
  $firmTab->setTabLabel("Company");
  $firmTab->setLocked("true");
  $firmTab->setXPosition("71");
  $firmTab->setYPosition("250"); 
  $firmTab->setWidth("80");
  $firmTab->setValue($_SESSION['company']); 

  // add postcode tab
  $postcodeTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
  $postcodeTab->setDocumentId("1");
  $postcodeTab->setRecipientId("1");
  $postcodeTab->setPageNumber("1");
  $postcodeTab->setName("postcodes");
  $postcodeTab->setTabLabel("Postcodes");
  $postcodeTab->setValue($postcodes);
  $postcodeTab->setLocked("true");
  $postcodeTab->setXPosition("66");
  $postcodeTab->setYPosition("312"); 
  $postcodeTab->setHeight("226");
  $postcodeTab->setWidth("500");
  // add the Company/postcodes tab to the envelope's list of tabs
  $tabs->setTextTabs(array($firmTab, $postcodeTab));
```

Comment: Hi CodingDawg, Thanks for the help. I have tried amending the code as shown above but it is still not showing. Thanks.

Comment: Note, I have added $firmTab->setValue($_SESSION['company']); as this seemed to be missing but it is still not working.

Comment: You cannot `setValue` on the company tab. Only the Signer can enter the value. The value will be automatically populated if the Signer already has a DocuSign account and has filled their company name in the Signer preferences.

Comment: Also try setting the WIdth of the company tab. The tab might be there but it could be too small for you to see. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have set the width as suggested but nothing is showing. Could this be because I am using a SandBox account?

I really would like to populate multiple tabs with pre-filled data. There are currently three more in total. As Andrew suggested I believe this can be done with a setTextTabs array but I am unsure how to do this with the PHP client.

Comment: Where is it not showing? In the Sender view? or during the signing ceremony.  As I said you will not be able to prefill the company tab. Its the Signers tab, only signer can fill it. You can also make  a GetRecipients call and see if the tab is indeed created.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24897732/1219543) on how to view the tabs created in an envelope.

Comment: During the signing ceremony. Where would I do a GetRecipients call? I do not recognise the folder structure.

Comment: Seems like I missed you in the chat. I will log back in at 9:00 GMT.

Comment: Okay, see you then. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I am in chat now :)